# Intellij: Is there any way to make navigating to the implementation of a symbol show up in the next pane, like in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

In VSCode (just like in Intellij), **Cmd+Click** on a symbol jumps to its definition/implementation, but **Cmd+Alt+Click** does the same except it shows the content in the next pane, leaving the current pane view undisturbed. Is there any way to configure Intellij to do this?

This is very useful while browsing through code to see the details of some symbol, but without disrupting the view in the current pane.

Comment: Have you tried to disable "Open declaration source on the same tab" option in "settings/Preferences | Advanced Settings - Editor Tabs"?

Comment: "Open declaration source on the same tab" does not seem to have any effect - with the option on or off, it navigates to the source in the same tab. This is on Intellij Idea Ultimate - 2022.3.2, with Kotlin source code

Comment: Please try to disable "Enable Preview Tab" in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Editor Tabs"